# Qt QAbstractItemModel multithreading

Tags: multithreading, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I plan to do something like this:

```
    QtConcurrent::map(rowsPool, [this](int nRow) {
        MyDataPtr spData;
        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&gModelMutex);
            const auto modelIndex = pModel->index(nRow, eData1);
            spData = pModel->data(modelIndex, eData2).value<MyDataPtr>();
        }
        ....
    }
```

Would this be the right approach?

Comment: Maybe, depending on your other code. Just remember that _modifying_ the model emits signals. So probably you should only modify the model from a single thread, and for each connect consider using Qt::QueuedConnection to reduce amount of code being executed inside mutex lock.